# ¿Porque cuando me da error de sintaxis al hacer INSERT INTO en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Esta es la función en php que uso para insertar datos en mi tabla usuarios

```
<?php
include 'includes/conexion.php';
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$contraseña = $_POST["contraseña"];

$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id_usuario, nombre_usuario, contraseña_usuario) VALUES ('','$usuario','$contraseña')";

if($conexion->query($consulta)){
    header("location: registar.php?created");
}else{      
    echo "Error al ingresar datos del post ".$consulta.$conexion->error;
    exit();
}
```

?>

**Y lo que obtengo es esto**

> Conecta a la base de datosError al ingresar datos del post INSERT INTO
>   usuarios (id_usuario, nombre_usuario, contraseña_usuario) VALUES
>   ('','abisur','aiShinozaki23')You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '�a_usuario) VALUES
>   ('','abisur','aiShinozaki23')' at line 1

Me puede explicar porque pasa esto, puesto que ya revise los campos y están correctos

Comment: id_usuario  es de tipo entero o varchar? de ser asi tienes que pasar el valor correcto. es auto_increment? de ser asi no debes hacer referencia al hacer el insert osea debes obviar el campo.

Comment: Dos recomendaciones básicas , 1. Modifique el nombre de sus campos en la base de datos y en los `name`  de los imput , no debería usar caracteres como `ñ`  , 2.- Utilice sentencias preparadas para evitar un posible [Inyección de código SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: El núcleo del error está aquí: `for the right syntax to use near '�a_usuario`  y es debido a que no estás estableciendo una codificación adecuada, por eso el programa cambia la `ñ` por el carácter inspector. Por eso se recomienda usar nombres de tablas/columnas que no contengas caracteres especiales, ñ, letras acentuadas, etc. Prueba a cambiar el nombre de la columna que tiene `ñ`  y si no puedes, [establece una codificación adecuada en todo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967). Una vez resuelto este problema, considera dar seguridad a tu código, como ha señalado @Dev.Joel.

Comment: tambien el hecho de que si tu id es primary key y auto increment no debes ni declarar el nombre de la columna ni las comillas vacias que pusiste al inicio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cuando declaras en tu tabla un id de tipo incremental y que aparte es
>   llave primaria, no es necesario ni declarar al nombre de la columna ni
>   su valor; por lo tanto tu query debería quedar así:

```
<?php
include 'includes/conexion.php';
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$contraseña = $_POST["contraseña"];

$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre_usuario, contraseña_usuario) VALUES ('$usuario','$contraseña')";

if($conexion->query($consulta)){
    header("location: registar.php?created");
}else{      
    echo "Error al ingresar datos del post ".$consulta.$conexion->error;
    exit();
}
```

> Como puedes observar quite el nombre de la columna y las comillas
>   vacias que dejabas donde pasas los valores

En el caso de que tu campo id no sea ni aunto incremental ni llave primaria por defecto; que lo hayas declarado como varchar o int nadamas, entonces tu query deberia lucir asi:

> Donde como notas pase un valor 1 en lugar de las comillas simples que
>   aun no entiendo por que pusiste

```
<?php
include 'includes/conexion.php';
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$contraseña = $_POST["contraseña"];

$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id_usuario, nombre_usuario, contraseña_usuario) VALUES (1,'$usuario','$contraseña')";

if($conexion->query($consulta)){
    header("location: registar.php?created");
}else{      
    echo "Error al ingresar datos del post ".$consulta.$conexion->error;
    exit();
}
```

> Cuando ingresas valores numéricos como en este caso pudiera ser el id,
>   no necesitas ponerlo entre comillas; en caso contrario si se trata de
>   fecha o cadenas de texto entonces si usa las comillas
>
> A sí mismo no uses caracteres especiales como ñ, acentos o cualquier
>   otra simbología que no pueda comprender tu gestor de bases de datos si
>   no lo configuraste adecuadamente

Comment: Podrias aclarar que si el campo es numerico, el valor no va entre comillas simples, y si es varchar, si va asi?

Comment: @gbianchi lo acabo de añadir al final de la respuesta, espero sea util mi comentario

Comment: no es que no necesitas.. NO DEBES, porque es un error.

Comment: entiendo @gbianchi di una respuesta incorrecta permiteme quitarla saludos

Comment: La respuesta esta bien!! solo aclara que si son numeros van siempre sin comillas.. y los otros van con comillas ;)

Comment: ¿Pero el error sigue ocurriendo, no? ya que el error mostrado en la pregunta es por la "ñ" de contraseña_usuario y no por el id

Comment: @track3r son varios errores tanto el uso de la ñ y despues si el escenario es como lo describo le va a votar el error que menciono además recuerda que si la respuesta no esta en función de la pregunta debes dar un -1

Comment: Gracias, lo solucione cambiando el nombre del campo contraseña por password_usuario